# Define Display Name for Models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

When I use visual studio scaffolding options for `Creating MVC View,using Entity Framework`, Visual Studio create Views and put name of Model on top of each View and also use DisplayName for field labels. i.e it cares about `Display` annotation for fields. e.g. Here is my model class:

```
namespace ProjectManager.Models
{
    [Display(Name="A More Readable Name for my class to display it to users!")]
    public class MyVeryComplicatedlyNamedModel
    {

         [Display(Name="نام(Description for name field in Unicode)")]            
         string Name;
    }
}
```

The automatically generated view for it is like below:

```
@model Project.Models.MyVeryComplicatedNamedModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>MyVeryComplicatedNamedModel</h4>

    ....
    ....
```

I want to know are there any methods to set DisplayName for class itself, such that title of view which displayed as h4 tag (`<h4>MyVeryComplicatedNamedModel</h4>`) be more readable and I can select my own description? The key point is I don't want to manipulate automatically created views to do so and I want to use some sort of annotation to help Visual Studio to select my own description for class name,

Using syntax `Display(Name='')` leads to error `Attribute 'Display' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'method, property, indexer, field, param' declarations.`

Comment: Why you want it on a Class ?

Comment: To automatically put readable name of class inside views.

Comment: Sorry ! I am still having trouble understanding what you are trying to do ? What you want to do in views again ?

Comment: @VSB: Where is the class name even *used* in the views?  It's not clear at all what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @Shyju I want make my classes such that, when related views of them are created, they look more readable. Currently VC just put name of class in start of each view which is not suitable for reading by users, so I want to do the same thing for class name that `[Display(name="")]` does for fields.

Comment: @David class name are inserted in created views using scaffolding options as headings.

Comment: **which is not suitable for reading by users** Which name are you talking about ? If you are talking about @model SomeClass, It is not for Users to read, It is for Razor to understand what type your view is bound to.

Comment: @VSB: What are you talking about?  Instead of vaguely trying to describe what is in your view, show it in the question.

Comment: Why would your users be reading your class names? They should have no knowledge or care what you call your classes.

Comment: @David I've just edited question. I hope you can have an answer for this after all that! :)

Comment: @VSB: That's just text in a view.  You can edit it directly.  It's not using any kind of automated display of the name of the class, that's just the only thing Visual Studio knew to put there initially.

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: this answer was posted before asker's clarification that manual modification is not what asker was after...

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class Students
    {
      public readonly string DisplayName = "University Students";
    }
}
```

then in view

```
<div>@Model.DisplayName</div>
```

As an alternative - if you want to stick to an attribute (I can't see why, but...) you may be able to resort to another one that existed called DisplayNameAttribute, but then you may have to do some ugly retrieval inside the view, as I am not aware of an Html Helper that does it for you.

Comment: Currently a tag like `<h4>Students</h4>` added in start of each automatically generated view. In case of Models with names like UnitBasedContractPaymentRequest  this tag will be `<h4> UnitBasedContractPaymentRequest</h4>` in automatically generated views. I'm looking for a way to force VS to use my desired name inside automatically generated views. Do you know any method for this (Which does not need to manipulate views after their generation)?

Comment: I just updated my question. Per your comment, default scaffolding of Visual Studio seems so limited.

Comment: @VSB You have to create your custom scaffolding: Check this blog post: [How to Create Custom Scaffold Templates in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/create-custom-scaffold-templates-asp-net-mvc/)